# End Kernel panic 15.10 live usb

Tags: kernel

So, I have a live USB stick that was running fine for a month or so. Decided to install Ubuntu on the hard drive, and then got this problem when I tried to boot from the stick to get out a few files.

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

*Any way i can get the files out?*

Answer (score 0):

Just:

1. Boot from the hard drive
2. Insert the stick
3. Execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop /media/szUserName/szMountPoint/casper-rw /mnt
   ```

   where your replace `szUsername` by your user name and `szMountPoint` by the mount point created by your USB installation.
4. Copy the files you need from `/mnt`...

*instead of booting from the stick...*  (Looks like the stick has a problem, so do this as quickly as possible *before* it goes down the drain...)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Cannot get to the files through normal USB use, probably different file system..? And drive is brand new, only been used to run Ubuntu for this month

Comment: @Aasvik Casper file system? Ecrypted File system? You don't know??? What do you see? ;-)

Comment: Casper, yes. Ive made the live usb through pendrivelinux, and the stick has only been used to run ubuntu live.

Comment: @Aasvik: answer edited

Answer (score 0):

Solved through mounting Casper file system, code:

```
sudo mount -o loop /media/aasvik/UUI -rw /media/casper
```